# How to add buttons below our site in the results of a search?

Tags: html, web

after several hours of research i cannot find a topic that explains how to add buttons below our site in google search results for example: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **`Google Sitelinks`**. Check out [this](https://bloggingwizard.com/google-sitelinks/) blog post.